# how to get each data from a parseJSON array

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to draw a linechart by using Google chart API, and I am use PHP codeignitor to retrieve data from mySQL database.

So far, I am able to retrieve the data, but I just couldn't parse the Json data, and fill them into linechart. below is the view I am actually loaded.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  // Load the Visualization API and the line package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

     $.ajax({

   type: 'POST',
    url: BASE_URL+'index.php/Chart_varnish/getdata',
    dataType: "json",



    success: function (data1) {
    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'timeline');
  data.addColumn('string', 'solid');
  var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data1);

  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        data.addRows([jsonData[i].timeline, jsonData[i].solid_t1]);
  }
  var options = {

    title: 'Solid chart',
    width: 900,
    height: 500,

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
   }
});
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="line_chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here under is the function getdata in my controller:

```
    function getdata(){
  $this->load->model('Chart');
  $this->load->helper('url');
    $data  = $this->Chart->getdata_solid();
    print_r(json_encode($data, true));
}
```

I tried to output the json_encode data, and I am able to get the result below:

```
[{"timeline":"430","solid_t1":"12"},{"timeline":"030","solid_t1":"8.1"},{"timeline":"830","solid_t1":"32"},{"timeline":"1230","solid_t1":"10"},{"timeline":"1630","solid_t1":"100"},{"timeline":"2030","solid_t1":"8"}]
```

Can someone help me on this, thanks.

**Update**

Hi Guys, I put the function in my model here, maybe because my query result is array, not a object?

```
function getdata_solid(){
  $this->db->select('timeline');
  $this->db->select('solid_t1');
  $this->db->from("varnish_mvs");
  $this->db->where('date_selected', '2017-03-25');
  //$this->db->where('timeline', $timeline);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();

}
```

**Final Update**: I finally solved this issue by changing the way of loading google chart functions. here under are my final working codes. I hope it may help for someone who has the same issue.

> 

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $.ajax({

   type: 'POST',
    //url: 'http://localhost/charts/charts/getdata',
    url: BASE_URL+'index.php/Chart_varnish/getdata',
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data1) {

     // alert(data1);
       // Load the Visualization API and the line package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    drawChart(data1);
  });

   }
});

     function drawChart(data1) {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'timeline');
  data.addColumn('number', 'solid_t1');
  var dataArray = [];
  /*$.each(data1, function(i, obj){
    dataArray.push([obj.timeline, parseInt(obj.solid_t1)]);
  });*/
  var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data1);
   for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        dataArray.push([jsonData[i].timeline, parseInt(jsonData[i].solid_t1)]);
      }
  //dataArray.push([jsonData[0].timeline, parseInt(jsonData[0].solid_t1)], [jsonData[1].timeline, parseInt(jsonData[1].solid_t1)])
  //dataArray.push(['2', 3], ['6', 5]);
  alert(dataArray);
  data.addRows(dataArray);
  var options = {
    title:'Solid chart',
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
     }

});
```

Comment: try after replace `print_r(json_encode($data, true));` to `echo(json_encode($data, true));`

Comment: `json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 ] )` - the 2nd argument should not be true/false

Comment: I tried 'echo', also tried put 'false', it still now showing the chart

Answer (score 0):

This

```
dataType: "json",
```

ensures that you are expecting json as response ([documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)), so you don't need to do

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data1);
```

`data1` is already a javascript object

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried to remove 'var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data1);', but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's problem, I don't have any error message. Just got a blank page instead. If I don't use the JSON data, just put manually some data, I can see a linechart on my page.

Comment: Try to console.log data to verify that your script retrieve the data correctly, first.

Comment: Thanks IIario, I got the error message like this: index:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.success (index:62)
    at Function.handleSuccess (jquery.min.js:141)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onreadystatechange (jquery.min.js:140)

Comment: Doing `console.log(data1)`? That's wierd... did you commented the remain part of the code during the debug?

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
    $.post(BASE_URL+'index.php/Chart_varnish/getdata',function(data1){
      $.each(data1,function(index,value){
      data.addColumn(value.timeline,value.solid_t1);
         });
//more CODE HERE
    },'JSON');
```

I hope it will help you solve the problem. you should also want to echo the json like this

```
echo json_encode($data1);
```

Comment: Hello, I am new to ajax, as well as new to programming. Could you please give me more guide on how to apply your code? I should replace all my ajax, then put your code in place? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Hello, sorry for late reply.. please read this article documentation.. if you have more questions. IM happy to help you.. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I do need to understand how it works, before go further.

Comment: you can apply your code above. I just change your ajax way..you can put your google draw in the "more code here" line..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the response from the PHP script is JSON data then you could probably process the response data like this.

```
function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASE_URL + 'index.php/Chart_varnish/getdata',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            var dataTbl = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                /* a number for at least 1 column is req'd ? */
                dataTbl.addColumn('string', 'timeline');
                dataTbl.addColumn('string', 'solid');

            /* iterate through the response data */
            for( var n in response ){
                if( response[n] && typeof(response[n])=='object' ){
                    dataTbl.addRows( response[n].timeline, response[n].solid_t1 );
                }
            }
            var options = {
                title: 'Solid chart',
                width: 900,
                height: 500,

            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart( document.getElementById('line_chart') );
                chart.draw( dataTbl, options );
        }
    });
}
```

The PHP script should simply use `json_encode` - the second argument can be a bitwise combination of flags ( predefined constants ) rather than a simple true/false - it is the `json_decode` function that uses /true/false as it's 2nd argument.

```
function getdata(){
    $this->load->model('Chart');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data  = $this->Chart->getdata_solid();

    /* echo rather than print_r */
    echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

Comment: I tried to copy your code to my script, however, I still couldn't get the chart. How do I know if the response from PHP script is JSON data?

Comment: Use the console in the browser and look at the response data.

Comment: I got the error message like this: index:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.success (index:62)
    at Function.handleSuccess (jquery.min.js:141)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onreadystatechange (jquery.min.js:140)